# SQL select value from top child record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Below is my table

TABLE A

```
Signature Parent
001
002        001
003        002
004        002
005        001
006        003
007       
008        007
009        008
```

Now i need to get Signature from top record (this one with no parent) for every child. I could call this OrgSignature.
OrgSignature is the same for every child.

```
Signature Parent OrgSignature
001
002        001       001
003        002       001
004        002       001
005        001       001
006        003       001
007
008        007       007
009        008       007
```

So for example how to get 001 signature as OrgSignature for 006 record?

I don't know how to explain this better... In table A i have some records with parent and some without parent. For each record i can create child:

```
001 -> 002
            -> 004
            -> 005
    -> 003
            -> 006
                    -> 007
```

There are relations between record 002-007 but for each record there is 1 top record - 001. And i need to get this top record signature for every child in this hierarchy.

Comment: Show us what code you have tried so we can see you have attempted to solve this problem.

Comment: Type your question with some code to understand your expectation.

Answer (score 1):

I think a recursive cte would be required here considering the variable depth of your hier

```
Declare @Hier table (Signature varchar(10),Parent varchar(10))
Insert into @Hier values 
('001', null),
('002','001'),
('003','002'),
('004','002'),
('005','001'),
('006','003'),
('007', null),
('008','007'),
('009','008')

;with cteP as (
      Select OrgSignature   = Signature
            ,Signature
            ,Parent
      From   @Hier 
      Where  Parent is null
      Union  All
      Select p.OrgSignature
            ,r.Signature
            ,r.Parent
      From   @Hier r
      Join   cteP p on r.Parent = p.Signature)
Select A.Signature
      ,A.Parent
      ,OrgSignature = case when Parent is null then null else A.OrgSignature end
 From cteP A
 Order By 1
```

Returns

[image]